# Optional dependency class in Spring Boot Library

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I'm creating a library for in house use and i want to add `spring-cloud-starter-sleuth` as an optional dependency so in the library's pom file the following is defined

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

and in the class where i'm using the tracer i marked it optional

```
@Configuration
public class EventPublishingAutoConfiguration {
    @Autowired(required = false)
    private Tracer tracer;
    ...

    @Bean        
    public Publisher publisher() {
        return new Publisher(tracer);
    }
}
```

In the publisher

```
public class Publisher {
    private Tracer tracer;

    public Publisher(Tracer tracer) {
        this.tracer = tracer;
    }

    ...
    public void publish() {
         if (tracer != null) ...
    }
}
```

Now when i'm trying to import it in one of my project which doesn't have sleuth getting the following error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/Tracer
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:613) ~[spring-core-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:524) ~[spring-core-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:510) ~[spring-core-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:570) ~[spring-core-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:697) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:640) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:609) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1490) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:425) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:395) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:96) ~[spring-context-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687) ~[spring-context-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:525) ~[spring-context-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.15.RELEASE.jar:1.5.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.15.RELEASE.jar:1.5.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.15.RELEASE.jar:1.5.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.15.RELEASE.jar:1.5.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.15.RELEASE.jar:1.5.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.15.RELEASE.jar:1.5.15.RELEASE]
    at com.demo.eventtest.EventApplication.main(EventApplication.java:16) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.Tracer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
```

UPDATE: I tried removing the usages of Tracer from auto configuration and the class where its used and it didn't give this error, so this is the only place where its being used.

Any reason why its still trying to load `Tracer`?

Comment: It fails because it cannot search for a bean in the ApplicationContext when the beans class/type is not available at runtime. You would need to check whether the class is in the classpath before trying to inject it maybe look [ConditionalOnMissingClass](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html#boot-features-class-conditions)

Comment: Created a wrapper for Tracer and put that class with a `ConditionalOnClass` helped.

Comment: If fails because the `EventPublishingAutoConfiguration` imports that class and thus it is needed on the class path. It doesn’t matter if it is marked optional with the `@Autowired` the class is still being loaded. Instead create on conditional rule on the configuration and instead of the class use a string reference. Finally make the actual configuration an static inner class to prevent it from being loaded. (Take a peek at some of the spring boot configuration class for inspiration).

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum yes it helped.